# Metl - transform date format

Tags: transform

I am looking at metl product to integrate data, somehow I need to transform a current date to my database format, I have look through this 
https://github.com/JumpMind/metl/wiki/transformer but this is quite general, can anybody provide a sample on how to perform transform ?

I am using currentdate(yyyyMMdd) but it return exception. I want to convert to a varchar format.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `parseAndFormatDate(parsePattern, formatPattern)`

For example:

```
parseAndFormatDate('yyyy-MM-dd', 'yyyyMMdd')
```